# Is it possible to embedded a Sqlite database into an excel 2007 file (zip archive)

Tags: excel, sqlite, odbc

I'm working on an excel application that requires a database back end. My preference is to use SQLite 3 and to make this as seamless and portable as possible for the end user.

Recently I have learned that an Excel 2007 file is simply a zip archive with a xlsm extension.  My question is this, can I store my back-end SQLite 3 database in the Zip archive and use ODBC to interact with the database. If so, can anyone point me to some background information, articles, guidance on achieving this objective.  Are there any downsides to this approach or a better alternative I should know about.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You are aware that Excel sheets can be VeryHidden and that you can interact with organized Excel data using ADO?

Comment: Why do you need SQL? Do you need multi-user access to the same data?

Comment: My data has a lot of dimensions and I will likely have to combine databases from numerous spreadsheets. I just thought this could be achieved more easily with a SQLite file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes. So far, no one has complained that the file does not open. Note that the Excel file is saved before the ADO code is run.

Very hidden:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Courses").Visible = xlVeryHidden
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("System").Visible = xlVeryHidden
```

A snippet of code:

```
    Const gCN = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
```

<...>

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

scn = gCN & ThisWorkbook.FullName _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

cn.Open scn

''If they do not have an ID, they do not exist.

sSQL = "SELECT ID,FirstName,LastName, " _
& "CourseName,AdditionalText,Format(ExpiryDate,'dd/mm/yyyy') As ExpiryDate " _
& "FROM [Applicants$] WHERE DateCancelled Is Null AND ID Is Not Null " _
& "AND (FirstName Is Null OR LastName Is Null Or CourseName Is Null " _
& "Or ExpiryDate Is Null) " & sWhere

rs.Open sSQL, cn
```

References:

[Excel ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)
[Connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Most of the methods available to Jet can be used with Excel

[Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

**Edit re Comments**

I did not find the leak particularly bad, but I did not run many iterations, and this is quite a good machine.

The code below uses DAO, which does not cause a memory leak.

```
'Reference: Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sDb As String
Dim sSQL As String

sDb = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(sDb, False, True, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;")

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(i)
    Next

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
db.Close
ws.Close

 'Release objects from memory.
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
```

Acknowledgement: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37398

Comment: Be aware of this method, there's a memory leak bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319998

Comment: That bug applies to quite old versions running with Jet. The current provider is ACE and 2013 will be released soon enough. The applies to link shows **APPLIES TO**
Microsoft Excel 2000 Standard Edition -- 
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet 4.0 -- 
Microsoft Excel 97 Standard Edition -- 
Microsoft Excel 2002 Standard Edition

Comment: It does, but the issue also applies to 2003 which isn't listed. I'd appreciate it if you could point me to somewhere that states that the ADO bug is fixed as I'd find it useful

Comment: Actually taking this a little further, using the code on the kb and updating to an ACE driver, I can reliably recreate the bug - so it appears that this is still an issue

Comment: Great :) +1 should be noted that you can also use DAO if Access isn't installed, but some DAO versions may cause leaks also as per your link

Comment: I ran with the leak testing code and the latest Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object Library, as referenced above, and got no leaks at all on 10 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative.

1) At Open (EVENTs in VBA) unzip from  Excel .xlsm, sqlite and dbFile.

2) Process what you .....

3) At save  (EVENTs in VBA) the book an then attach the  Excel .xlsm ,sqlite , dbFile in Excel .xlsm.

Answer (score 1):

Excel rewrites the file every time it is saved, so your own added file would be deleted.
Furthermore, there is no SQLite driver that can access database files inside of zip archives.

You would have either to ship the database file alongside with the Excel file, or to recreate the database with a list of SQL commands when your application detects that the DB file is missing.
This still requires that some SQLite (ODBC) driver is installed on the user's machine.

The most seamless and portable way to store data in an Excel file is to store it in an Excel sheet, as mentioned by Remou. However, it's possible that the ADO driver will refuse to open the file when it's already open in Excel, so that you have to use Excel functions to access the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It appears I need to investigate Remou's suggestion of storing the data in hidden sheet and using ADO.  I haven't come across this approach in the past but I'm sure there must be some articles on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://code.google.com/p/pyinex/
this embed the Python interpreter in Excel