# Finding all possible permutations (with certain values) of multiple tables in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, permutation

First time poster, long time lurker.  I've learned a lot reading from this site.

Ok, so first I created code already to do this in excel but I know it is highly inefficient (nested for loops) and it takes hours to run (Right now I run 6 seperate excel threads and it still takes 5-6 hours as each thread goes through about 5 million permutations).

My thoughts were that Access would be a much better way to accomplish my goal, but I have almost 0 knowledge of Access. (I do have all my tables imported into Access fine)

Essentially, I'm looking at 2 criteria for 7 items (1 item coming from each of 7 tables) and one of those combined values must be greater than a specific number while the other combined values must be less than a specific number.  There also must be no duplicates (there are some duplicates between the tables).

To try to explain better:

Table 1    __    Table 2    __     Table 3        ......

1, x, y    __     1, x, y  __       1, x, y

2, x, y     __    2, x, y    __     2, x, y

.....

10, x, y  __      6, x, y  __  7, x, y

What I'm looking for would be the combination of items from Table 1 - Table 7 that has no duplicates, all x values added together > specific number, and all y values added together < specific number.

So ultimately it would come up with something that may look like:

1, x, y

7, x, y

2, x, y

10, x, y

3, x, y

4, x, y

6, x, y

sum of all x > specified number

sum of all y < specified number

Hopefully this is specific enough to explain my problem.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit - 
I've now gotten more information thanks for the help below ... here is where I am at:

Using a union query similar to below.

I still can't figure out how to base the results off the total sum of the value and cost fields.  I need the value field totals to be greater then a specific number and the cost field totals to be below a specific number.

`Select Category, Name, Value, Cost`

`From Table`

`Where Category ="1"`

`Union`

`Select Category, Name, Value, Cost`

`From Table`

`Where Category ="2"`

....
....

Comment: Did you have created the seven tables with three fields each?. If yes, what are the names of each field in the tables?

Comment: Yes - Name, Value, Cost

Comment: Why 7 tables? Have you looked at a UNION query? BTW you can use DAO in Excel to run queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068022/is-it-possible-to-embedded-a-sqlite-database-into-an-excel-2007-file-zip-archiv/13196464#13196464

Comment: Well each table represents a separate category. I guess the logic behind it (at least in excel) is so these categories are kept seperate while going through all the permutations.  Only a couple of the tables have duplicates between them.

Comment: Looking at the Union query, it seems that would absolutely be on the right track.  Can you run the union query so it bases it's findings on the total sum of each of the fields it is looking for?

Comment: I suggest you add a category column in MS Access and combine all the tables into one. It is almost never a good idea to translate Excel directly to MS Access. Excel is essentially linear whereas Access is relational. You can refer to a union query in a sub query -- SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...) AS UQ WHERE UQ.F1 ..., but that will be irrelevant once you normalize.

Comment: (ASIDE: To ensure a Stackoverflow user who has made a comment is notified of a response, you can use @<username>)

Comment: @Remou - I edited the bottom of my question above so it was more readable with my code.  I think I have the basics of the query - but still don't understand how to use the overall totals of the two fields.

Comment: When you say total, do you mean total including duplicates or excluding duplicates?

Comment: Excluding duplicates @Remou

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is not in the **UNION** since **UNION** Does't group values. I think the query what are you looking from is the following extended to 7 tables. I made it with three because you can understand the basics better.

```
SELECT T1.NAME, T1.VALUE, T1.COST, 
       T2.NAME, T2.VALUE, T2.COST, 
       T3.NAME, T3.VALUE, T3.COST
FROM TABLE AS T1, TABLE AS T2, TABLE AS T3
WHERE T1.CATEGORY = '1'
  AND T2.CATEGORY = '2'
  AND T3.CATEGORY = '3'
  AND T1.VALUE + T2.VALUE + T3.VALUE > X
  AND T1.COST+ T2.COST + T3.COST < Y
```

X and Y are your specified values. You have to replace them for your values.

Notice that in this way you have all the values in the same row for identifying the groups. I hope that be what are you looking for.