# performance issues when importing large csv file into mdb using ADO

Tags: vba, excel, csv, fastercsv

This is my code, but its taking about an hour to export all 17 million rows into mdb. I cannot use mysql or sql server for this purpose. I have to do it in access db and quickly coz this process runs once in a week. Plz suggest the fastest method available for this task

```
Sub insertDataIntoMDB()
 Dim Dbfilepath As String
 Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        Dim arrData() As String
        Dim s As String
        Dim i As Integer


        Dbfilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DB\Interface.accdb"
        cnn.Open "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & " Data Source=" & Dbfilepath & ";" & "Persist Security Info =False;"

        q1 = "DELETE * FROM MYTABLE"
        Set rs = cnn.Execute(q1)

        'q1 = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN ID autonumber(1,1)"
        'Set rs = cnn.Execute(q1)

        p = UserForm1.csvFolder & "\" & sItem & ".csv"

        Open p For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)

          Close #1


            Line Input #1, s
            arrData = Split(s, ",")
           q1 = "INSERT INTO MyTable(F1,F2,F3) values(" & arrData(0) & "," & arrData(1) & "," & arrData(2) & ")"
           Set rst = cnn.Execute(q1)
        Loop
        Close #1
        rs.Close
        rs`enter code here`t.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        cnn.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cnn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: please tell something more about all tables you work with (MYTABLE) and CSV file, how do they look like? (structure, data), etc.

Comment: Any reason why you do noy wish to use MS Access? Eg. DoCmd.TransferText ?

Answer (score 0):

Right here you have a huge slowdown and potential for data corruption.

```
q1 = "INSERT INTO MyTable(F1,F2,F3) values(" & arrData(0) & "," & arrData(1) & "," & arrData(2) & ")"
Set rst = cnn.Execute(q1)
```

String concatenation is slow, especially in VBA. So as soon as you write `"something" & "something"` and put it in a loop you're asking for slow performance.

Also, Access is usually faster with DAO than with ADO.

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987017/2250183)
[And maybe this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522023/how-do-i-insert-800000-records-into-an-ms-access-table/522056)

If you insist on using ADO you might want to open a recordset with a SELECT statement then append your data to that recordset, followed by a call to UpdateBatch.

[You can read more discussion here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=289518)

Good luck!